# While Loop Syntax Error

Tags: apt, bash, scripts

I'm attempting a modification of apt-fast to support parallel downloading and installation.

I'm having some trouble with this loop:

```
get_install(){
while ((!${pkg}-finished))
do
  if [ "$CURNUM" -lt "$_MAXNUM" ]; then
    let CURNUM=$CURNUM+1
    eval "aria2c -c -j ${_MAXNUM} -x ${_MAXNUM} -s ${_MAXNUM} \
           -i /tmp/${pkg}-dl --min-split-size=1M --connect-timeout=600 \
           --timeout=600 -m0 && find -type f -name "$(cat /tmp/${pkg}-name)" \
           -execdir mv -ft "$APTCACHE" {} \+ && \
           ${_APTMGR} -y install $(cat /tmp/${pkg}-name) \
           "${APTCACHE}/$(cat /tmp/${pkg}-name)" && let CURNUM=$CURNUM-1 && \
           ${pkg}-finished=1 &"
  else
    eval "sleep 1 &"
done
}
```

(Code slightly edited for readability, versus source.)

It's giving me:

```
/usr/sbin/apt-fast: line 297: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
/usr/sbin/apt-fast: line 297: `done'
```

I'm sure it's something minor I'm overlooking. If anyone needs a copy of the whole script, it's here: http://www.filedropper.com/apt-fast_1 I'll take any other critiques on it as well!
To try running it you may need to install apt-fast from the ppa first, instructions here: https://github.com/ilikenwf/apt-fast After installing, just overwrite /usr/sbin/apt-fast with the one linked above.

Comment: I think you have missed `fi` before `done`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As g_p said in the comments, your `if [ "$CURNUM" -lt "$_MAXNUM" ]` isn't terminated. Bash is expecting a `fi` before the `while`'s `done`.